# sql to eloquent - nested select to apply group by

Tags: mysql, eloquent, subquery

I would like to perform the following query in Eloquent.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select
        `id`,
        `category`,
        `name`,
        `slug`,
        `value`,
        `value_validation`,
        `value_type`,
        `created_at`
    from
        `configurations` 
    order by `created_at` desc
) as `a` GROUP BY a.slug;
```

Essentially, I need to store a history of all configurations in the DB. So will not be using the updated_at field, but rather creating a new row every time the configuration is updated. The old configuration will then no longer be used and the latest will always be applied.

`slug` is not unique. But my intention is for the group by statement to ensure that I get back a unique `slug`.

I want to be able to use all of Eloquent's goodness - and as such, would ideally want an eloquent object - not a query builder object.

Here's what I have so far, which generates the inner query. Now all I need to do is modify it to apply the outer query.

```
$configurations = $this->configuration
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: what's the expected result? you are selecting all columns but grouping only by slug, there are no guarantees that you will get the most recent row, result will be undetermined

Comment: @fthiella - The expected result is that I have an eloquent query that performs the exact sql query explained above. The guarantee is that I have first ordered by `created_at desc` which means that my results are in the correct order. When I apply group by in the outer query, I will always get the first item in the group - ensuring that I have the latest result.

Comment: In example above, `slug` is not unique. So when i order by created_at, and then apply the group, I always get the latest version.

Comment: the problem is that this feature is undocumented and it is considered bad practice, there are no guarantees that you will get the first item in the group, the optimizer might choose to return a different row and not always the first